# Question about web service and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I almost finished Orielly ASP.NET 3.5 book, now I am at the chapter on web services.. I read it a bit and wondered why do I really need it for?

Is it about building web applications and hosting them on a proxy?

What does it give me knowing web services and WPF, cause they didnt teach me that in school!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean web services and **WCF**?

If so, then they are both flexible ways of communicating between distributed systems. If you ever work on an commercial eneterprise system you are almost certainly going to need that knowledge. As a hobbyist you will probably need it when writing a Rich Client Web App such as Silverlight, Ajax or if you ever develop a mobile application that synchronizes data with a central server.

It gives you a lot ;)

Comment: I do want to use a rich client web application.. is hosting the site on a proxy..gives you  a boost in performance/security..why do developers use the WCF?

Comment: WCF is a much more configurable, flexible option and has cross platform support (good for Ajax, java calls) webservices are mainly for .NET consumers and require some tinkering if you want to call them from other platforms.

Comment: So if I want to apply for a job right now..would the employer expect me to know web services. I have one site built (Forum like), but if learning WCF is mandatory at every asp.net job, I have to learn it , right?

Comment: I would imagine they would expect a basic knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Web services is a very very important topic to learn as you will come to a situation where you have a functionality that you want to be share between your website, mobile application and your windows application so in this case you will develop the code 3 times while with web service you have this feature developed once and used everywhere.

Here is an example, if you want to calculate the number of off days between 2 dates so you have develop that code what if their is a webservice that already do that so when a new day is added to the off days, all dependent website will be working on the new values and will not need to update their code.

Comment: But I can save dates in a database.  How do webservices substitute the creation of a functionality that i already can make by adding code files or another database?

Answer (score 1):

Web services are about separating off features and functionality onto different servers. Or, to put it another way, fronting features and services available on servers for access by other applications.

Do you need to know about them? It depends on what you want to do. If you are only ever writing stand-alone, self-contained applications then maybe not, but many web sites use web services to provide certain facilities.

For professional work they are very important to knwo about and understand. For a hobbyist, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically about [decoupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling#Software_Development) a part of your application in favor of reusability and interoperability.

You could, for example, want a back end system which is able to communicate independently with both an asp.net web site, a windows application, and an iPhone mobile app. That's what web services are for.

[This article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) has a good explanation too.

Comment: hmmm...so it is a good practice for certain design patterns...like MVC type of thing?

Comment: It's a method of communication, which definitely helps you implementing some architectural design patterns (like MVC for example).